# OnPush & templates: Pushing changes to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a parent component which has two templates ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-update-parent?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)):

1. the first contains a simple data-bound text
2. the second contains a child component which updates data model (from its `constructor` and `ngOnInit` in this demo)

Here is the parent component template:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="true">
  <div>
    <b>Value from TemplateComponent: </b>{{ dataService.value | async }}
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template [ngIf]="true">
    <template-component></template-component>
</ng-template>
```

Both parent and child components are `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and this is a requirement.

The issue is that the data updates starting from `ngOnInit` (and later ones) of the child component don't get picked up by the change detection in the parent component. This causes the parent component in the demo to display:

> Value from TemplateComponent: value from constructor

instead of

> Value from TemplateComponent: value from ngOnInit

since the CD picks up an update on constructor stage only, but not in `ngOnInit` and later:

```
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {
    public constructor(public readonly dataService: DataService) {
      this.dataService.setValue("value from constructor");
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
      // This update is NOT picked up by CD in parent component
      this.dataService.setValue("value from ngOnInit");
    }
}
```

Except this approach with `markForCheck()`, I've also tried a simple `@Output` event in the child, but it obviously doesn't work, since the child is created via `ng-template` and actually is not a direct child of the parent component.

Could someone give an idea of what is the cleanest and  Angular's `OnPush`-friendly approach for passing data to the parent from `ng-template` created control?

**P.S.:** By

> the cleanest and  Angular's `OnPush`-friendly approach

, I mean something that keeps all parts (components and service loosely-coupled), for example, without involving `setTimeout()` or other dirty fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You've grasped the idea of using observables, async pipes and OnPush strategy, but the problem is that you have to go a little deeper and understand how angular component lifecycle events work.

Let's see what happens (simplified version)

1. Parent component `constructor()`
2. Child component `constructor()`
3. Parent component `onInit()` - evaluate @Input templates and ngIf directives
4. Child component `onInit()` - trigger changes to some properties used in parent
5. Parent `afterViewInit()`

Once `onInit` in child component is called, the directives in parent component were already evaluated! From angular perspective content inside `[ngIf]` template is already what it is suppose to be and there's need to run change detection again or update anything.

**You shouldn't change data that is used in parent component from onInit() in child component, otherwise you will surely break something.**

If you wait until all components are fully instantiated and trigger change, then all views will be updated.

eg. in your child component:

```
setTimeout(()=>this.dataService.setValue("hello"),1000)
```

That also works, if you try to `markForCheck` in `ngAfterViewInit` in your parent component

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
  }
```

or if you won't use `*ngIf` the value will be re-evaluated.

```
<div><b>Value from regular div: </b>{{ dataService.value | async }}</div>
```

All of mentioned workarounds are not advisable, just don't change data from child component's `onInit` and you will be fine.